# Is Exclusive in XOR really appropriate for more than two inputs?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, boolean, logic, xor

What does Exclusive in XOR really mean for more than two inputs? Doesn't word Exclusive suggest only one input must be true and not odd number of inputs. Note that the inputs are in sequence.
This may seem like duplicate question but all similar questions answer for only two inputs and hence causes me confusion.

Comment: Are the inputs to be XOR in sequence or parallel? e.g. 1 XOR 0 XOR 1 (sequential) or 01 XOR 11 (parallel)?

Comment: The inputs are in sequence.

Comment: Thanks. If they were in parallel then I was going add another answer. You might want to update the question for others in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exclusive OR is defined for two operands only, like e.g. addition. Just like an addition, it happens to be *associative*. This means

```
(a xor b) xor c = a xor (b xor c)
```

for all inputs *a*,  *b* and *c*.

For associative operations, it is customary to drop parentheses because they cannot change meaning of an expression:

```
(a + b) + c = a + (b + c) = a + b + c
(a xor b) xor c = a xor (b xor c) = a xor b xor c
```

One can loosely speak of xor-ing together a bunch of values, but the underlying operation always takes two operands.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But few of my teachers said disagree but I agree. Its even printed in an uncertified book(XIIth State board Computer Science) in Karnataka State in India that it accepts three input. Anyways, you solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because there is no reason in logic or in the design of electronic circuitry that XOR cannot be defined for more than two inputs. 

`XOR(a1,a2,...an)` conceptually means that *exactly one* of the arguments a1,a2,...an must be true.

Comment: @MattClarke of course one can define such an operation, but please don't call it "exclusive or" to avoid horrible confusion. Thank you.

Comment: What confusion? Would you say that AND and OR can't have more than two operands? Why not?

Comment: I just read http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93713/how-is-an-xor-with-more-than-2-inputs-supposed-to-work. Now I can see the confusion.